# Bottom navigation view is overlapping some portion of the content(fragment)

Tags: android, xml, bottomnavigationview, android-framelayout

I am using the following xml code. The problem is the bottom navigation view is overlapping some portion of the last item of the framelayout. Is there a way i could solve this problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground" />



</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Either use margin or padding or add dummy `Space` widget which is height of Bottom navigation, then you have to use `LinearLayout` for this warped for `FrameLayout`

Answer (score 0):

simple solution is you should set android:paddingBottom for FrameLayout to size of BottomNavigationView's height